# SwiftUI -- Handling Interactions in Form

Tags: forms, button, swiftui

I'm creating a more complex UI that consists of several sub-parts, each sub-part is enclosed in a `Section` and all sections have to go in one `Form`
As soon as several `Button`s belong to one `Section`, each `action` of the `Button`s is triggered as soon as one `Button` is clicked.

In the following code

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var cnt = 0
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section (header: Text("Counter")){
                HStack {
                    Button("Increment"){
                        print("Inc")
                        cnt += 1
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Decrement"){
                        print("Dec")
                        cnt -= 1}
                }
                Text("Counter : \(cnt)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

a tab one one of the two `Button`s triggers both actions. By adding `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` to each `Button` or by removing the `Form` everything works as expected. Unfortunately the real UI is more complex and relies on the `Form` widget. The `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` removes the visual hint that the elements are active.

Is there a different way to solve my problem?

Comment: Form is one of those take it or leave it views. It is meant to look and behave like the basic Apple forms. It is doesn’t work for you just create the minor visual elements that you like.

Comment: try with .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())

Comment: Thanks jay, that is surely a step in the right direction.